# HarePoint Knowledge Base and DevExpress won't leave me alone!

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, feature

I installed the HarePoint Knowledge Base for SharePoint.  I have since removed it.  Periodically, despite the fact that I have removed every trace of the application I can find, all of my web.config files are rebuilt and have these three lines added, which cause the site to not work since the files no longer exist.  I have search the registry, file system, database, etc., and haven't found anywhere else to remove it from.

```
<add name="HarePointKnowledgeBaseASPxHttpHandlerModule2" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v12.1, Version=12.1.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c350d55b9850baf2" />
<add name="HarePointKnowledgeBaseHttpModule" type="HarePoint.KnowledgeBase.Http.HKBHttpModule, HarePoint.KnowledgeBase, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=619eb34ec30b4b26" />
<add name="HarePointKnowledgeBaseASPxHttpHandlerModule2" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v12.1, Version=12.1.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c350d55b9850baf2" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" />
```

What can I do to make this go away?

Comment: did you remove the lines from web.config files?

Comment: I removed them from the web.config for each of the virtual directories, but they occasionally get regenerated by some process within SharePoint (I'm not sure if it is deployment of another solution or tied to restarts, or what causes it), and then they are back in the web.config file.  At that point, the websites won't work because they can't find the file, and the web.config needs to be manually cleaned up again.

Comment: then i would recommend check couple of things...System settings > manage farm solutions and see something here....also check the assembly gac folder and see if something here(if yes then delete it manually).